# automapper dll appears in root of project in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, automapper

In the MVC project I updated the from AutoMapper 3.1.0 to AutoMapper 3.1.1 and now I see `AutoMapper.Net4.dll` in root of the project in Solution Explorer.

[image: automapper in solution explorer]

When I browse to the directory of the project the .dll is not there at the root of the project as shown in Solution Explorer. 
When I view its properties in Solution Explorer I see that the file is properly located in `packages\AutoMapper.3.1.1\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll` under my project. The application itself seems to work fine.

So I'm wondering what is happening here? Because I've never seen this before.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I reverted back to version 3.1.0 and no such issue is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was removed in the 3.2 beta version. I now use a PowerShell script to force the .Net4.dll to be copied to the bin folder (sometimes MSBuild won't).

Comment: I don't understand it. I just installed the AutoMapper from Nuget (it shows version 3.1.1), but the dll appears in two places, once in root of the project and another in References. Is it really required that way, or I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: The beta version requires you to use the Prerelease option in NuGet. With the beta, you'd see 3.2.0

Comment: Yes Got that. I can see the version 3.2.0 now. Thanks.